# Перевод массива в число типа int и обратно

Tags: c, массивы, микроконтроллеры, uart

Программирую контроллер от Silicon Labs (C8051F120), сейчас решаю задачу по передаче информации через интерфейс UART (конкретно-частоты в МГц). Он воспринимает введенное число как массив:

> UART0_ComBody[0], UART0_ComBody[1], UART0_ComBody[2] и т.д.

То есть 153 МГц будет разбито по отдельным цифрам. `1, 5 и 3`.
Как можно перевести массив `UART0_ComBody[]` в число типа `int`, чтобы произвести с ним вычисления?
И перевести его обратно (для дальнейшей передачи)?

Comment: Какого типа массив (элементы массива) `UART0_ComBody`? Почему этой информации не указано в вопросе?

Comment: Согласен, надо было указать. Это объявляется как unsigned char  UART0_ComBody[UART0_MAX_COMBODY_LENGTH];

Comment: Добавленная вами картинка не имеет отношения к первоначальному вопросу. Я её убрал.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Например, так:

```
int digits2int(int *list, int n) {
  int res = 0, i, pow;
  for (i = n-1, pow = 1; i>=0; --i, pow*=10) {
    res += list[i] * pow;
  }
  return res;
}
```

---

Полный текст программы:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int digits2int(int *list, int n) {
  int res = 0, i, pow;
  for (i = n-1, pow = 1; i>=0; --i, pow*=10) {
    res += list[i] * pow;
  }
  return res;
}

int main() {
  int input[3] = {1, 2, 4};
  printf("Result: %d", digits2int(input, 3));
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, но ругается что  'digit2int': missing function-prototype.(когда пытаюсь вернуть значение Digit2int из вашей функций)

Comment: Если это не опечатка в digit**s**2int, то вы пытаетесь использовать функцию до её объявления. Можете воспользоваться forward-declaration - просто напишите сигнатуру функции `int digits2int(int *list, int n);` в начале файла

Comment: Неа, вашу функцию вставил в самое начало кода. Даже если в начале еще раз написать Int digits2int... то все равно выдает те же ошибки. См. картинку сверху

Comment: Сравните внимательно `digits2int` и `digit2int`

Comment: Дайте ей своё название, в конце концов)

Comment: ошибка исправлена. Но что значит  too few actual parameters и 
 illegal pointer conversion??

Comment: Значит, что вы неправильно её используете. Я добавил рабочий вариант использования в ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Если у вас массив целых чисел, то достаточно написать элементарный цикл:

```
int arr[] = { 1, 5, 3 };

int value = 0;
for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(arr) / sizeof(*arr); ++i)
{
    value *= 10;
    value += arr[i];
}
```

Если массив ASCII символов, то немного изменится правило вычисления:

```
char arr[] = { '1', '5', '3' };  
// ...
value += arr[i] - '0';
```

Для *NULL*-терминированных строк можно вовсе использовать функции `atoi`/`stoi`.

Обратный перевод делается тривиально. Если возникнут сложности, могу дополнить ответ.

Comment: А если у нас не постоянно 153 Мгц, а значение, которое вводится с клавиатуры?

Comment: @Оскар т.е. Вы не знаете как массив заполнить?

Comment: Как заполнить его введенными с клавы числами- нет, не знаю

Comment: @Оскар это вполне может быть отдельной темой для обсуждения. Но вообще-то, об этом есть в любом учебнике по языку.

Comment: @Оскар на Stack Overflow не приветствуется впихивать в один вопрос много разных тем. Если выявляется проблема в чём-то существенно другом - задавайте отдельный вопрос. Это бесплатно.